# The completion of the linear span of exponential functions on an interval

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let the functions $\{  e^{2 \pi i n t} \}$ (for all natural $n$) be the vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Here $e^{2 \pi i n t}$  are functions (the variable $t$ is between $0$ and $1$).

I try to find the closure of this vector space. If I could show this vector space is an algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ which closed under conjugation I will finish, since I can apply Stone-Weierstrass Theorem. For these functions on $[0,1-\varepsilon]$ and conclude the closure is all the continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to  $\mathbb{C}$  such that $f(0)=f(1)$. But I don't know how to prove  this set is closed under  conjugation.

Comment: have you thought about Fourier Transform?

Comment: it should be solveable without it, anyway I couldnt find a way to use fourier

Answer (score 1):

It's more natural to think of these functions as defined on the unit circle in the complex plane. Then we look at the completion of the linear span of the functions $z^n$, $n=0,1,2,3\dots$.  Of course the completion depends on the norm we use. If the uniform norm is used, we get the [Disk Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_algebra). If $L^p$ norm is used, we get  the [Hardy space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space) $H^p$.

If by natural numbers you meant $n=1,2,3,\dots$ instead of $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$, then the result is the subspace of disk algebra / Hardy space that consists of the functions vanishing at $0$ (equivalently, having mean $0$ on the circle).

In any event, you **do not** get all continuous periodic functions: for example, $e^{-it}$ is not in the closure. The Stone-Weierstrass theorem does not apply, since the algebra is not  closed under conjugation.